# grails ehcache flush on demand without JVM startup

Tags: grails, jmx, ehcache

In our application we are using ehcache to store objects that may alive till the server startup.eternal set to true for the ehcache beans and we have the respective configurations in the resources.groovy.

In some case the data loading is not happening properly and this is happening in prod alone and we can't restart the prod jvm's frequently.
Is there a way to flush these ehcache beans on demand without restarting the server and without any deployments.

I heard like with jmx console there are possibilities to acheive it but not able to find blog posts related like flushing ehcache objects via jmx console in grails..

Please provide some suggestions or ideas as hardly trying to find a solution for this case but not getting enough information.

grails ehcache flush on demand without JVM startup

Comment: The answer depends on the versions you are using. Can you provide these?

Comment: We are using grails : 2.3.11 version.